# IBM Natural Language Processing Projects (Beginner getting started question)

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've been digging into the IBM Cloud Services, Watson and NLP. Just installed the CLI and tried with Node SDKs, and a starterkit, unfortunately I did not succeed by trying to get a sample code by default to understand how it works.

After that, I did some research get a better open minded approach to how actually I could use some of their free services to get started, but there's actually to vague information, even though the IBM Docs are pretty extensive and well written, it can get very confusing.

I would appreciate any open source repo, or working/live project that you are willing to share to make a better image in my mind about it IBM cloud services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago I wrote a sample application using the Natural Language Understanding service. Check the source code here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-understanding-code-pattern

The README has instructions on how to get the `apikey` which is the way you will use to authenticate your API calls.

Since you are using Node.js you can start with the sample above and also look at this page: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=node which includes examples for all the features in Node.js using the node-sdk: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/